# DAX custom Format

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need to apply a custom format to my measure, but not using the FORMAT function, only through the format panel selector.
Indeed, if I use the FORMAT function, all linked measures then return an error because (I assume) the result is no longer a number.

I applied the string # ##0, to display 730 instead of 730,200.
However, when I add text like # ##0, "M" the format is no longer applied and I Want 730 M

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you provide some sample inputs and what you want the outputs to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to the relationships view.

[image]

Then select your measure. You should then, under Properties, have a formatting section. Under there you can select a custom format and input what you want.

[image]

Here's are the results I got when changing the format of a measure that used to be of the currency format (i.e., the first value was once `£5,140`) to the format you specified.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works if numbers <1 000 000.
1074 356  should appear like 1 074 M...

Comment: OK, i found a workaround with a measure.